# Why it has to be a monad?

Tags: haskell

I've tried following code snippet on prelude:

```
*ExerciseMonad Control.Monad> :t fmap ((:) 3) []
```

and got as result an empty `[]`.

Then I convert an empty list to `monad` structure:

```
*ExerciseMonad Control.Monad> x = return []
*ExerciseMonad Control.Monad> :t x
x :: Monad m => m [t]
```

the returned value is wrapped in `Monad` structure.

It seems like a magic, that I do not get an empty list:

```
*ExerciseMonad Control.Monad> fmap ((:) 3) x
[3]
```

Why did not I get an empty list?

Comment: Okay, I'll ask the obvious counter-question: why would you expect `fmap f []` and `fmap f (return [])` to do the same thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`fmap` works on any `Functor`, including `[]`. Note how GHCi infers the type of your first expression:

```
Prelude> :t fmap ((:) 3) []
fmap ((:) 3) [] :: Num a => [[a]]
```

The return type is a nested list, because otherwise the cons operator (`:`) doesn't make sense. When you `fmap` over an empty list (`[]`), however, there's nothing to do, so the result is also the empty list.

On the other hand, the type of your second expression is different:

```
Prelude> x = return []
Prelude> :t x
x :: Monad m => m [t]
Prelude> :t fmap ((:) 3) x
fmap ((:) 3) x :: (Num a, Monad f) => f [a]
```

You'll notice that the return value is no longer a nested list, but a `Monad` over `[a]`. `Monad`, however, includes `Applicative`, which again includes `Functor`, so in this second expression, `fmap` is no longer the for the `[]` instance, but for `f`. As Lee points out, in GHCi, the default `Monad` is `IO`, so the `fmap` in `fmap ((:) 3) x` maps `IO`, not `[]`.

This means that `x` actually becomes `IO []` in GHCi, and `fmap` in the `IO` monad applies the mapping function to the data contained inside of the monad (`[]`). This means that you get `((:) 3) []`, which is `[3]`:

```
Prelude> ((:) 3) []
[3]
```

Answer (score 2):

In your first example `fmap ((:) 3) []` has type `Num a => [[a]]`. `fmap f [] == []`.

In contrast the type of `fmap ((:) 3) x` is `(Monad m, Num a) => m [a]`.[GHCi deafults](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html) `m` to `IO` so at the prompt it has type `Num a => IO [a]`. The corresponding IO action is evaluated and the result is printed if it is an instance of `Show`. `a` defaults to `Integer` and `[Integer]` has a `Show` instance so it is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

```
fmap ((:) 3) []
```

Would actually apply the `(:) 3` operator to the "contents" of your list functor. As you have no contents you normally get an empty list in return. If in case you had it like;

```
fmap ((:) 3) [[],[],[]]
```

then you would get `[[3],[3],[3]]` as the return value.

Now if you chose to feed `fmap` with a list value. You may feed it with a list value "wrapped" into List value constructor like;

```
*Main> fmap ((:) 3) $ return []
[3]
```